# Is there a benefit to using resource vs resources in your Rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

To have more than one route on a course resource, we use `resources :course`. We use the singular `resource` for only one route like `courses#new`. Is it feasible to use `resources :course` even if I have one route? I figure it would be easier later on to add course routes if it is already plural. Is there a downside to making resource plural from the get go?

Comment: Did my answer help in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Singular resources like:

```
    resource :course
```

generate only 6 routes instead of 7. So the plural index route is left. But the main reason for differing between singular/ plural resources is its expressiveness.
Sometimes, you have a resource that clients always look up without referencing an ID. For example, you would like /course to always show the current course. In this case, you can use a singular resource to map /course (rather than /course/:id) to the show action:

1. GET

   - /course/new
   - courses#new
   - return an HTML form for creating the course
2. POST

   - /course
   - courses#create
   - create the new course
3. GET

   - /course
   - courses#show
   - display the one and only course resource
4. GET

   - /course/edit
   - courses#edit
   - return an HTML form for editing the course
5. PATCH/PUT

   - /course
   - courses#update
   - update the one and only course resource
6. DELETE

   - /course
   - courses#destroy
   - delete the course resource

Also read [Singularize resource routes, if it is singular!](http://chris-on-rails.blogspot.de/2014/08/singularize-resource-route-if-it-is.html)

Please consider this for your decision. So if the course resource is singular in its context choose singular resource, otherwise choose multiple resources.